# How to determine if restaurant is part of franchise?

Tags: foursquare

I want to use the FourSquare api but I'm curious to know how or if I can figure out if a restaurant belongs to a franchise or not? Like all Starbucks/McDonalds will be part of their specific franchise ID.

Answer (score 0):

Foursquare provides information whether the restaurant is part of a chain or not. However this information is available only if Owner of the Restaurant chain has registered their business i.e. created a page regarding Business on the Foursquare.

The venue Details API yeilds the the page field in API Response. This contains the restaurant chain information.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/venues/details

Below is snippet for Pizza Hut seattle Venue details.

```
            "page": {
            "pageInfo": {
                "description": "Follow Pizza Hut on Foursquare and check in to your local store to share your love for pizza with all of your friends!",
                "banner": "https://is1.4sqi.net/userpix/WPQD1CUUGRQ510FD.jpg",
                "links": {
                    "count": 1,
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "url": "http://order.pizzahut.com"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "user": {
                "id": "910282",
                "firstName": "Pizza Hut",
                "gender": "none",
                "photo": {
                    "prefix": "https://igx.4sqi.net/img/user/",
                    "suffix": "/910282-FGR40Q3CQH0CGF3N.png"
                },
                "type": "chain",
                "tips": {
                    "count": 3810
                },
                "lists": {
                    "groups": [
                        {
                            "type": "created",
                            "count": 2,
                            "items": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "homeCity": "Dallas, TX",
                "bio": "",
                "contact": {
                    "twitter": "pizzahut"
                }
            }
        }
```

Check it contains **type** field which has value as **chain**